# What am I doing wrong with pure virtual methods and Google Mock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

## Intro

I'm having a problem with implementing a pure virtual interface using Google Mock (v1.7.0).

In order to determine the root cause, I've put together pure virtual interface `Simple` and `MockSimple` as a test. I believe what I have done here is in line with [this Google Mock example](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies#A_Case_for_Mock_Turtles).

Yet, when I compile it, I get an error. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

## Simple Test Code

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class Simple
{
public:
    virtual ~Simple() {}
    virtual int Initialize()   = 0;
};

class MockSimple : public Simple
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Initialize, int());
};

TEST(Hello, MockSimple)
{
    MockSimple m;
    EXPECT_CALL(m, Initialize);
    m.Initialize();
}
```

## Compilation Command

```
g++ -I../gmock/include/ -I../gmock/gtest/include  -c test.cpp -o test.o
```

## Error Output

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Hello_MockSimple_Test::TestBody()’:
test.cpp:20:5: error: ‘m.MockSimple::gmock_Initialize’ does not have class type
```

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861780/c-error-does-not-have-a-class-type

Comment: Shouldn't this be `MOCK_METHOD0(Initialize, int32_t ());`??

Comment: @TomásBadan I don't think so.

Comment: @g-makulik, I changed it, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need argument list (an empty one, in this case) for the method called in the EXPECT_CALL :)

```
EXPECT_CALL(m, Initialize());
```

Comment: U_U I feel stupid. I'm glad it was that easy to fix! Thank you!